# Java Spring: Use same request mapping for different parameter and return value

Tags: java, spring

I have two post calls. The first takes `User` object as a parameter, is mapped to `/login` and returns a `List`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<List<Login>> login(@RequestBody User user) {
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Login>>(HttpStatus.OK);    
}
```

the second takes `ApiToken` object as a parameter, is mapped to `/login/apitoken` and returns a `String`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login/apitoken", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> autheticateApiToken(@RequestBody ApiToken apiToken) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(authenticateApiToken, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I feel it is not a good design, so I want to combine it into one request mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/v1/login", "/v1/login/apitoken"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

But I do not know how to continue, since the two endpoints have different `RequestBody` and return method. Does anyone know how to combine these two request mappings into one? Or is the old function good enough?

Comment: Your current solution is fine.

Comment: If they do similar things, move the common part into methods called by both. The point of fine grained request mappings is that you don't have to write all the if-this-then-that logic needed to decide which handling code to use. If you would make a method that takes e.g. any `Object` you would start with exactly that. Different Response types is ok-ish to have, you can make the method return wildcard `ResponseEntity<?>` for that.

Comment: @zapl thanks for your reply. I would say these two function is not have two much related but similar endpoint and in the future some similiar code may be added to both function. In this case, do you think is it better to just keep current code?

Comment: Yes, different methods should go in different methods :) Keep it as is